# java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes

Tags: java, arduino-uno, ioexception, serial-communication

I'm trying to read arduino uno data using a java program with the help of rxtx library. I'm using COM8 serial communication port for this. I'm using win10.

my problem: when i'm using 'serial.print', then down java function working fine and retrieving everything that arduino sending. But when i try to use 'serial.write' in arduino then an ioexception occurs
 "java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes"
I dont know why.
my need is to use 'serial.write' method, please tell me what is wrong in code. both codes is down

Java Function code:

```
public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            try {
                String inputLine=input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        // Ignore all the other eventTypes, but you should consider the other ones.
    }
```

arduino uno code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 10);
void setup() {
    mySerial.begin(9600); // Setting the baud rate of Software Serial Library  
    Serial.begin(9600);  //Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor 
}
void loop() {
    if(mySerial.available() > 0) {
         Serial.print(mySerial.read());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `serial.println` which breaks the line in the end, while `serial.write` doesn't. On the other side the `readLine()` method of java reads the entire line, until it recorgnizes a line break.(\n)

**problem:** in case of `serial.write()`, there is no line break "\n", so `readLine()` is unable to find any line at all and results in `java.io.IOException: Underlying input stream returned zero bytes` 
atleasst one line break is required for `readLine()` to work.

**solution:** while using `serial.write()` manually provide line break statement("\n")